# Debugging powershell init

Tags: powershell, scripting, console, user-profile

My problem is that I just reinstalled my system and have installed heaps of packages via Chocolatey. However now when I launch powershell, something changes the fonst type and size inside the console to raster and 16pt (huge and ugly), even though my console defaults are truetype and 14pt. This happens even if I have my profile under Documents/PowerShell/... all commented out and I launch it from a regular console with "@powershell" or just "powershell.exe".

Can anyone tell me how to go about finding the problem? Things that fiddle with fonts is the poshgit installation as far as I saw in the chain of profile scripts that are run, but as I said, even if I have all of them disabled (seemingly), something still changes the font.

**Edit:** I have found that even a clean install in a virtual machine does the same thing. So how to set the fonts in Powershell? I have done everything the way as many tutorials say the clicking way, but it is not persistent.

Could anyone assist me?

Thank you in advance,
Máté

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found that others are having the same problem, just the keyword is Lucida Console.

[This](http://www.michaeladshead.co.uk/blog/?p=145) guy had a similar problem. Changing the size did not solve my problem, but if I changed to regular Lucida font type instead of Lucida Console, it was persistent. Lucida Console must interfere with some other part of the system which causes powershell to fallback to raster font.

Although this is sadly not an explanation, it's a viable compromise.

Answer (score 0):

There are several powershell profiles. I would suggest you examine all of them to see if code has been added. For example, using notepad, you could do the following:

```
> notepad $profile.AllUsersAllHosts
> notepad $profile.AllUsersCurrentHost
> notepad $profile.CurrentUserAllHosts
> notepad $profile.CurrentUserCurrentHost
```